# When should I stop a training of WGAN model?

Tags: deep-learning, gan

The loss function of the WGAN is a continuous one. It doesn't have a convergence point. I don't really understand when we should stop the training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loss of WGAN does have a convergence point: 0. We should arrive at this point when the generator is capable of generating samples so good that no Lipschitz continuous discriminator can distinguish real from generated samples.

In fact it is a major selling point of WGAN that the loss should steadily converge in a way that informs you whether the training is making progress or not. With traditional GANs, pretty much the only way of telling if the generated samples are improving is via visual inspection, and you stop the training when the visual quality of the samples is satisfying.

Comment: But how the WGAN loss goes to zero ?  Do you think with weight clipping we can get that 0 convergence?  What would happen if we over train the whole WGAN system ? Do you think still discriminator will give the same score to real and fake

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana like with any neural network, it's unrealistic to expect convergence. But in theory with ideal function estimators and optimizers yes, it will converge to 0.

Comment: But I thought we can't have a convergence in WGAN

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04406.pdf - Check this out